# How can I reset a while loop in python so that all conditions are the same as when it started?

Tags: python, loops, reset

I'm trying to code a game that:

- draws a random number
- asks user to enter guess
- if the guess is too low or high it will print a statement accordingly
- if it takes user more than 3 guesses it prints("three strikes you're out")
- if user guesses it it prints("you guessed it")
- in both cases it would then ask user if they want to play again.
- if yes, program should generate new number and strikes should go back to zero
- if no, break

The problem I am having is that I can't figure out how to generate the new random number and reset the strikes to zero when user has guessed the number or lost.

```
import random



game_stop = False

strikes = 0

random_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,]

random_number = random.choice(random_list)

def play_again():
   play_again = input("play again?: ")
   if play_again == "yes":
       strikes = 0

       game_stop = False
       return random.choice(random_list)


while not game_stop:

   strikes = strikes + 1

   guess = input("enter guess: ")

   if guess == "exit":
       break

   if int(guess) > random_number:
       print("too high")
   elif int(guess) < random_number:
       print("too low")
   else:
       print("you guessed it!")
       print("It took you " + str(strikes) + " tries!")


       play_again()


   if strikes > 2:
       print("three strikes your out!")
       play_again()   '''
```

Comment: You're returning unnecessarily - replace `return random.choice(random_list)` with `random_number = random.choice(random_list)`

Comment: Thanks but its still not working. It doesn't reset the count or redraw the number. I'm thinking it has to do with some local global variable discrepancy in the play again() function

Answer (score 0):

Modify your play_again() function, use `raw_input` instead of `input`:

```
def play_again():
   play_again = raw_input("play again?: ")
   if play_again == "yes":
       strikes = 0

       game_stop = False
       return random.choice(random_list)
```